# How to use Objective-c NSTimeZone to convert system timezone to destination's local timezone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a project which involved in converting current time on iPhone to target destination's time. For example, the application needs to convert current time (08:00) to Germany's local time.

I have information about timezone (like UTC +1) and tried to search about how to use NSTimeZone to convert the NSDate value, but it looks like I have to ask your help here.

Could you give me any suggestion? or point me out for some solution?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is probably to use -[NSTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:] for each time zone, and then figure out the delta between the two:

```
NSInteger  offset1 = [timezone1 secondsFromGMTForDate: date];
NSInteger  offset2 = [timezone2 secondsFromGMTForDate: date];

return [date addTimeInterval: (offset1 - offset2);
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben. But how can I initial timezone object? for example, do I need to convert from local date in time zone (+7) to destination date in timezone (+1).

Comment: There are a number of initializers for NSTimeZone; probably use either +timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: or + timeZoneWithName:. You mentioned that you already had information about the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Check out NSDateFormatter and its [setTimeZone:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBICCJE) method.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide on working with time zone differences from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID) might be a useful guide to follow.